# Xamarin Dynamically Update specific DataTemplate item Property in CollectionView with unique value

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, monodevelop

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding ProductDb}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="{Binding ItemStatus}" />
                <Label Text="{Binding ItemId}" />
                <Label Text="{Binding ItemDescription}" />
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

The collectionView is first loaded from the database and wait for a specific event occurring in the code. The `ItemStatus` for all Item data property initially has the same message "Still in progress".

Then later when an event occurs it has to update the `ItemStatus` for a specific Item Data in `CollectionView` with new message "Completed !"

The event is just a regular C# method with a timer in it.
After 2 minutes it has to updates one `ItemStatus` property and changes its message to "Completed".

I tried to update `ItemStatus` from OnPropertyChanged of INotifyPropertyChanged but it updates all the ItemStatus for each Item data with the same value.
I know it's normal behaviour because ItemStatus property name find itself within each Item data.

I also tried to use x:Name for ItemStatus Label but it doesn't work; and I read on Microsoft web site that DataTemplate creates a new scope for all the elements inside of it,

I was also thinking about creating dynamic elements but not sure if it's gonna work.

**By the way, I want to dynamically only update ItemStatus for specific ItemId/Item Data,**

I remember in HTML/CSS/Javascript there is kind of CLASS and ID element that you can access from javascript method anywhere in the page.

**Please does anybody have an idea how to achieve it?**

```
private string itemStatus = "Still in progress";

public string ItemStatus
{
    get => itemStatus;
    set
    {
        if (value == itemStatus)
            return;

        itemStatus = value;     
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ItemStatus));
    }
}


private void UpdateUIItemStatusMessage(string uniqueMessage)
{
    ItemStatus = $"Completed !!!";
}
```

[image]

**Requested code by Jason**

```
namespace WarehouseMobile
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ProductPage : ContentPage
    {
        private string itemStatusMessage = "Still in progress";

        public string ItemStatus
        {
            get => itemStatusMessage;
            set
            {
                if (value == itemStatusMessage)
                    return;

                itemStatusMessage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ItemStatus));
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<ProductDb> _products;
        public ObservableCollection<ProductDb> Products
        {
            get { return _products; }
            set
            {
                _products = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Products));
            }
        }

        public ProductPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BindingContext = this;

            Products = new ObservableCollection<ProductDb>();
        }

        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            Products = new ObservableCollection<ProductDb>(data);
            myCollection.ItemsSource = Products;
        }
        
        private void UpdateUIItemStatusMessage(string itemId)
        {
            var myItems = myCollection.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<ProductDb>;

            var selectedItem = myItems.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == 4);

            selectedItem.ItemStatus = $"NEW MESSAGE !!! - Completed";
        }
    }
}

public class ProductDb
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
        public string ItemStatus { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: @Jason Thank you Jason for trying to help me out. The XAML code has a lot of things in it. I cleaned it and removed styling and some unrelated codes.

Comment: @Jason The default value for ItemStatus is **Still in progress** and it loaded from the database when the collectionView loads for the first time.     What I want to achieve is after it loads the default value, I should be able to update like ItemStatus for ItemData2 (ItemId2) with value "Completed" if an event occurs in the code. The event is not a problem so far, the main issue is to update ItemStatus for a specific ItemId with a specific value.

Comment: @Jason It is being called for every object because the property named "ItemStatus" is found in every object. I need a way to locate the property **ItemStatus ** for a specific Item Data I want.

Comment: Just to remind you that **ItemStatus** property works fine, its event really fires but it updates all the data in the CollectionView DataTemplate. If I use your code `selectedItem.ItemStatus = $"NEW MESSAGE !!! - Completed";` to only update specific Label element, there it doesn't update anything.

Answer (score 0):

> The event is not a problem so far, the main issue is to update
> ItemStatus for a specific ItemId with a specific value.

If you want to update the property of special item of the data list bind to `CollectionView` , you need to implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` for your item model(`ProductDb.cs`).

Secondly,it is recommended that you use [MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm) to implement your function.

And I have achieved this function,you can refer to the following code:

**ProductDb.cs**

```
public class ProductDb: INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
        // public string ItemStatus { get; set; }
        private string _itemStatus;
        public string ItemStatus
        {
            set { SetProperty(ref _itemStatus, value); }
            get { return _itemStatus; }
        }

        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;
            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

**ProductViewModel.cs**

```
public class ProductViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    //private string itemStatusMessage = "Still in progress";
    //public string ItemStatus
    //{
    //    get => itemStatusMessage;
    //    set
    //    {
    //        if (value == itemStatusMessage)
    //            return;

    //        itemStatusMessage = value;
    //        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ItemStatus));
    //    }
    //}

    private ObservableCollection<ProductDb> _products;
    public ObservableCollection<ProductDb> Products
    {
        get { return _products; }
        set
        {
            _products = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Products));
        }
    }


    public ProductViewModel() {
        Products = new ObservableCollection<ProductDb>();

        Products.Add(new ProductDb { ItemId = 01, ItemDescription = "ItemDescription 1",ItemStatus = "Still in progress" });
        Products.Add(new ProductDb { ItemId = 02, ItemDescription = "ItemDescription 2", ItemStatus = "Still in progress" });
        Products.Add(new ProductDb { ItemId = 03, ItemDescription = "ItemDescription 3", ItemStatus = "Still in progress" });
        Products.Add(new ProductDb { ItemId = 04, ItemDescription = "ItemDescription 4", ItemStatus = "Still in progress" });
        Products.Add(new ProductDb { ItemId = 05, ItemDescription = "ItemDescription 5", ItemStatus = "Still in progress" });

    }

    bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;
        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

}
```

**ProductPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class ProductPage : ContentPage 
    {
        public ProductPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ProductViewModel viewmodel = this.BindingContext as ProductViewModel;

            var selectedItem = viewmodel.Products.FirstOrDefault(o => o.ItemId == 04);

            selectedItem.ItemStatus = $"NEW MESSAGE !!! - Completed";
        }
    }
```

**ProductPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:formsecondapp="clr-namespace:FormSecondApp"
             x:Class="FormSecondApp.ProductPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <formsecondapp:ProductViewModel></formsecondapp:ProductViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>

            <Button  Text="update status" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Products}">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding ItemStatus}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding ItemId}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding ItemDescription}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
            
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```